# custom taxonomy search error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I updated wordpress core package to latest Ver.
And I got some DB error and my website search logic does not work.
In my  test wp-site, the logic works well and I don't know how can I fix it.

I added custom post type 'estate' and some custom taxonomies such as 'key-prices','key-areas' as to use in my search checkbox, via wp-plugin "Custom Post Type UI".
And setting the taxonomies to custom field as check box select keys in wp-plugin "advanced custom field"
And using wp-plugin "Search Everything" to include my custom fields into serach sesult.
So, I thought I could have good code to add custom taxonomies to my wordpress keyword search. It works in my test WP-site.

I think the difference between test and public is post content and setting values via admin panel. And core WP version.(test WP-site = WP4.9.1 english/public WP-site = 4.9.1 japanese)

I checked my test WP-site by wp-plugin "Query Monitor" and it return these errors.

---

(query)

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND ((())) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'estate'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

---

(call stack)

```
wp()
wp-includes/functions.php:960
WP->main()
wp-includes/class-wp.php:715
WP->query_posts()
wp-includes/class-wp.php:599
WP_Query->query()
wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:3222
WP_Query->get_posts()
wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:2821
```

---

(component)

### core

(error code)

### 1064

(error message)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'estate' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR ' at line 1

And I conpare good working query code in test WP-site and bad query code in public WP-site.

### (test site)

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'estate'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

---

(public site)

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND ((())) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'estate'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

### wp()

The public WP-ste's line4 is wrong.

```
AND ((()))
```

But I can't find out how can I fix it.

Does someone help me?
I really need someones help...

[image: screenshot]